# win32 batch files: gather and concatenate all matching files

Tags: winapi, batch-file

In a Windows batch file, I want to construct a classpath of .jar files in a trusted directory.

I thought this might work:

```
set TMPCLASSPATH=
for %%J in (*.jar) do set TMPCLASSPATH=%TMPCLASSPATH%;%%J
```

This doesn't seem to work, since `%TMPCLASSPATH%` appears to be evaluated once at the beginning of the for loop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion, you add SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION to the top your batch file, and use ! rather than % around the variable names.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set TMPCLASSPATH=
for %%j IN (*.jar) DO set TMPCLASSPATH=!TMPCLASSPATH!;%%j
echo %TMPCLASSPATH%
```